# Add quantity Prestashop button cannot read property 'top', why?

Tags: jquery, prestashop-1.6, typeerror

Good morning,

I have an add quantity button (Prestashop) and everytime i click it works, but when out of stock it need to appear a error message that is out of stock.

What's wrong with this Js?

Error log attached on post below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var GetaName = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('a[name="'+GetaName[1]+'"]').offset().top},1000);
});
});
```

[image: error-log]

Comment: Hi Sasha, could you post the error as plain text? by editing the question

Answer (score 0):

the error in te screenshot says that `$('a[name="'+GetaName[1]+'"]').offset()` does not exists.

This means that `$('a[name="'+GetaName[1]+'"]')` returns `null`.

You should check if `$('a[name="'+GetaName[1]+'"]')` exists before checking is offset.